Icons in the bottomNavigation from react native paper are only partially visible and incorrectly positioned
I’m using react-native-paper's BottomNavigation with MaterialCommunityIcons. The icons in the bottom navigation bar are not fully visible, and their positions appear misaligned on the page.
preview
Here's a simplified version of the code I'm using:
  labeled={false}
  navigationState={{ index, routes }}
  onIndexChange={setIndex}
  renderScene={renderScene}
  renderIcon={({ route, color }) => (
    <MaterialCommunityIcons
      name={route.focusedIcon}
      color={color}
      size={48}
    />
  )}
  barStyle={{
    height: 60,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  }}
  activeColor="blue"
  inactiveColor="gray"
/>

After inspecting with the developer tools, I found that the maximum height and width for the icons were restricted to 32px. When I manually increased the size to 48px in the developer tools, the icons displayed correctly.
Why is the width and height capped at 32px, and how can I properly adjust the icon size within the component?
Here's what I've tried:

Added padding and tried setting width and height for the icons.
Set justifyContent and alignItems in barStyle to center the icons.

Despite these changes, the icons still display only a portion of their expected size, and their positions are incorrect. I've also adjusted the height of the barStyle but still can't get the icons to display properly. What am I missing? Any help would be appreciated!

The restriction is most likely due to react-native-paper limiting the size of icons for visual consistency across different devices, try the following:

Override the style on renderIcon
renderIcon={({ route, color }) => (
  <MaterialCommunityIcons
    name={route.focusedIcon}
    color={color}
    size={48} // Keep the size here for consistency
    style={{ width: 48, height: 48 }} // Add this to ensure the correct size is applied
  />
)}



Modify barStyle
barStyle={{
  height: 60,
  justifyContent: 'center',
  alignItems: 'center',
  paddingBottom: 5, // Add padding if needed to adjust the alignment
}}



use iconSize prop
<BottomNavigation
  labeled={false}
  navigationState={{ index, routes }}
  onIndexChange={setIndex}
  renderScene={renderScene}
  renderIcon={({ route, color }) => (
    <MaterialCommunityIcons
      name={route.focusedIcon}
      color={color}
      size={48}
    />
  )}
  barStyle={{
    height: 60,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  }}
  activeColor="blue"
  inactiveColor="gray"
  iconSize={48} // Check if this helps with size adjustments
/>





It works with style={{ width: 48, height: 48 }}! Thank you so much

youre welcome, happy coding!, glad I could be of help
